# Sleep is sleeping the whole programme

Tags: c++

When I press the up arrow key a star moves up 2 time but I want to add a delay between the star moving the 1st and 2nd time, this is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

char Map[10][20] = {"###################",
                    "####    #########!#",
                    "####  # ######### #",
                    "####* # ######### #",
                    "#     # ######### #",
                    "# ##### ######### #",
                    "# ##### ######### #",
                    "# ##### ######### #",
                    "#@#####           #",
                    "###################" };

int Gamespeed = 100;
int Level = 1;
bool stopgame = false;
int Hp = 100;
int MaxHp = 100;

int main()
{
    while(stopgame == false && Level == 1)
    {
        system("cls");
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            cout << Map[y] << endl;
        }
        cout << "Hp: "<< Hp << "/" << MaxHp << endl;
        for (int y = 0; y<10; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x<20; x++)
            {

                switch(Map[y][x])
                {
                    case '#':
                    {
                       Map[y][x] = 219;
                    }
                    break;
                    case '*':
                        {
                            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0)
                            {
                                if (y = 3)
                                {
                                    Map[y][x] = ' ';
                                    y -= 1;
                                    Map[y][x] = '*';
                                }
                                Sleep(1000);
                                if (y = 2)
                                {
                                    Map[y][x] = ' ';
                                    y -= 1;
                                    Map[y][x] = '*';
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case '@':
                    {

                        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0)
                        {
                            int y2 = (y-1);

                            switch(Map[y2][x])
                            {
                                case ' ':
                                {
                                    Map[y][x] = ' ';
                                    y -= 1;
                                    Map[y2][x] = '@';
                                }break;
                                case '!':
                                    {
                                        Level = 2;
                                    }break;
                                    case '*':
                                    {
                                        Hp -= 20;
                                        Map[y][x] = ' ';
                                        y -= 1;
                                        Map[y2][x] = '@';
                                    }break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0)
                        {
                            int y2 = (y + 1);

                            switch(Map[y2][x])
                            {
                            case ' ':
                                {
                                    Map[y][x] = ' ';
                                    y += 1;
                                    Map[y2][x] = '@';
                                }break;
                            case '!':
                                {
                                    Level = 2;
                                }break;
                                case '*':
                                    {
                                        Hp -= 20;
                                        Map[y][x] = ' ';
                                        y -= 1;
                                        Map[y2][x] = '@';
                                    }break;
                            }
                       }

                       if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) != 0)
                       {
                           int x2 = (x + 1);

                           switch(Map[y][x2])
                           {
                           case ' ':
                            {
                                Map[y][x] = ' ';
                                x += 1;
                                Map[y][x2] = '@';
                            }break;
                           case '!':
                            {
                                Level = 2;
                            }break;
                            case '*':
                                    {
                                        Hp -= 20;
                                        Map[y][x] = ' ';
                                        x -= 1;
                                        Map[y][x2] = '@';
                                    }break;
                           }
                       }
                       if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) != 0)
                       {
                           int x2 = (x - 1);

                           switch(Map[y][x2])
                           {
                           case ' ':
                            {
                                Map[y][x] = ' ';
                                x -= 1;
                                Map[y][x2] = '@';
                            }break;
                           case '!':
                            {
                                Level = 2;
                            }break;
                            case '*':
                                    {
                                        Hp -= 20;
                                        Map[y][x] = ' ';
                                        x -= 1;
                                        Map[y][x2] = '@';
                                    }break;
                           }
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Sleep(Gamespeed);
    }
```

this is the code that makes the star move

```
case '*':
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0)
        {
            if (y = 3)
            {
                Map[y][x] = ' ';
                y -= 1;
                Map[y][x] = '*';
            }
            Sleep(1000);
            if (y = 2)
            {
                Map[y][x] = ' ';
                y -= 1;
                Map[y][x] = '*';
            }

        }
    }
  break;
```

the problem is the Sleep is pausing the whole programme not the star moving

Edward Alejandro Medina's solution:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <chrono>

    using namespace std;

    char Map[10][20] = {"###################",
                        "####    #########!#",
                        "####  # ######### #",
                        "####* # ######### #",
                        "#     # ######### #",
                        "# ##### ######### #",
                        "# ##### ######### #",
                        "# ##### ######### #",
                        "#@#####           #",
                        "###################" };

    int Gamespeed = 100;
    int Level = 1;
    bool stopgame = false;
    int Hp = 100;
    int MaxHp = 100;

    int main()
    {
    chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> current_time,last_time;
    float delta_time,star_delay=0;
    current_time=chrono::system_clock::now();
    last_time=current_time;
    while(stopgame == false && Level == 6)
    {
           current_time=chrono::system_clock::now();
           delta_time=chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<float>>(current_time-last_time).count();
           last_time=current_time;
        system("cls");
        cout << "Well done you made it to level 6\n\n";
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            cout << Map6[y] << endl;
        }
        cout << "Hp: "<< Hp << "/" << MaxHp << endl;
        for (int y = 0; y<10; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x<20; x++)
            {

                switch(Map6[y][x])
                {
                    case '#':
                    {
                       Map6[y][x] = 219;
                    }
                    break;
                    case '*':
                        {
                                if (y == 8 && x == 12)
                                {
                                    Map6[y][x] = ' ';
                                    y -= 1;
                                    Map6[y][x] = '*';
                                    star_delay=0;
                                }
                                if (y == 7 && x == 12)
                                {
                                    Map6[y][x] = ' ';
                                    y -= 1;
                                    Map6[y][x] = '*';
                                    star_delay=0;
                                }
                                if (y == 6 && x == 12)
                                {
                                    Map6[y][x] = ' ';
                                    x += 1;
                                    Map6[y][x] = '*';
                                    star_delay=0;
                                }
                                if (y == 6 && x == 13)
                                {
                                    Map6[y][x] = ' ';
                                    y += 1;
                                    Map6[y][x] = '*';
                                    star_delay=0;
                                }
                                if (y == 7 && x == 13)
                                {
                                    Map6[y][x] = ' ';
                                    y += 1;
                                    Map6[y][x] = '*';
                                    star_delay=0;
                                }
                                if (y == 8 && x == 13)
                                {
                                    if(star_delay>1){
                                    Map6[y][x] = ' ';
                                    x -= 1;
                                    Map6[y][x] = '*';
                                    }else{
                                        star_delay+=delta_time;
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                        break;
                    case '@':
                    {
                        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0)
                        {
                            int y4 = (y-1);

                            switch(Map6[y4][x])
                            {
                                case ' ':
                                {
                                    Map6[y][x] = ' ';
                                    y -= 1;
                                    Map6[y4][x] = '@';
                                }break;
                                case '!':
                                    {
                                        Level = 7;
                                    }break;
                                    case '*':
                                    {
                                        Hp -= 20;
                                        Map6[y][x] = ' ';
                                        y -= 1;
                                        Map6[y4][x] = '@';
                                    }break;
                            }

                        }

                        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0)
                        {
                            int y4 = (y + 1);

                            switch(Map6[y4][x])
                            {
                            case ' ':
                                {
                                    Map6[y][x] = ' ';
                                    y += 1;
                                    Map6[y4][x] = '@';
                                }break;
                            case '!':
                                {
                                    Level = 7;
                                }break;
                                case '*':
                                    {
                                        Hp -= 20;
                                        Map6[y][x] = ' ';
                                        y -= 1;
                                        Map6[y4][x] = '@';
                                    }break;
                            }
                       }

                       if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) != 0)
                       {
                           int x5 = (x + 1);

                           switch(Map6[y][x5])
                           {
                           case ' ':
                            {
                                Map6[y][x] = ' ';
                                x += 1;
                                Map6[y][x5] = '@';
                            }break;
                           case '!':
                            {
                                Level = 7;
                            }break;
                            case '*':
                                    {
                                        Hp -= 20;
                                        Map6[y][x] = ' ';
                                        x -= 1;
                                        Map6[y][x5] = '@';
                                    }break;
                           }
                       }
                       if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) != 0)
                       {
                           int x5 = (x - 1);

                           switch(Map6[y][x5])
                           {
                           case ' ':
                            {
                                Map6[y][x] = ' ';
                                x -= 1;
                                Map6[y][x5] = '@';
                            }break;
                           case '!':
                            {
                                Level = 7;
                            }break;
                            case '*':
                                    {
                                        Hp -= 20;
                                        Map6[y][x] = ' ';
                                        x -= 1;
                                        Map6[y][x5] = '@';
                                    }break;
                           }
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Sleep(Gamespeed);
        while(Hp == 0)
            {
                system("cls");
                cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n                              you died on level " << Level << "\n\n                             better luck next time.";
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
     }
                    }
                }
            }
            Sleep(Gamespeed);
        }
```

Comment: Sleep holds the current thread. So it is expected only. Have you used any threads other than main?

Comment: no i have only used main

Comment: Yes it does. What do you expect?

Comment: so what part of the code should i change

Comment: `Sleep()` holds the current thread. It's parameter is time in ms so maybe the easiest way how to delay star movin' is just set a lower value

Comment: I have tried to use a lower number but the same thing happens, just faster

Comment: With the code it's pretty clear, you first change the map, then sleep, then redraw the screen. You have to redraw the screen before sleeping. Write a function to draw the map, this avoids code duplication.

Comment: If I redraw the map the at symbol wont be at the same spot as it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

char Map[10][20] = {"###################",
                    "####    #########!#",
                    "####  # ######### #",
                    "####* # ######### #",
                    "#     # ######### #",
                    "# ##### ######### #",
                    "# ##### ######### #",
                    "# ##### ######### #",
                    "#@#####           #",
                    "###################" };

int Gamespeed = 100;
int Level = 1;
bool stopgame = false;
int Hp = 100;
int MaxHp = 100;

int main()
{
chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> current_time,last_time;
float delta_time,star_delay=0;
current_time=chrono::system_clock::now();
last_time=current_time;
    while(stopgame == false && Level == 1)
    {
   current_time=chrono::system_clock::now();
   delta_time=chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<float>>(current_time-last_time).count();
   last_time=current_time;
        system("cls");
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            cout << Map[y] << endl;
        }
        cout << "Hp: "<< Hp << "/" << MaxHp << endl;
        for (int y = 0; y<10; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x<20; x++)
            {

                switch(Map[y][x])
                {
                    case '#':
                    {
                       Map[y][x] = 219;
                    }
                    break;
                    case '*':
                       if (y == 3)
                       {
                           Map[y][x] = ' ';
                           y -= 1;
                           Map[y][x] = '*';
                           star_delay=0;
                       }
                       if (y == 2)
                       {
                          if(star_delay>1){
                             Map[y][x] = ' ';
                             y -= 1;
                             Map[y][x] = '*';
                          }else{
                             star_delay+=delta_time;
                          }
                       break;
                    case '@':
                    {

                        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0)
                        {
                            int y2 = (y-1);

                            switch(Map[y2][x])
                            {
                                case ' ':
                                {
                                    Map[y][x] = ' ';
                                    y -= 1;
                                    Map[y2][x] = '@';
                                }break;
                                case '!':
                                    {
                                        Level = 2;
                                    }break;
                                    case '*':
                                    {
                                        Hp -= 20;
                                        Map[y][x] = ' ';
                                        y -= 1;
                                        Map[y2][x] = '@';
                                    }break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0)
                        {
                            int y2 = (y + 1);

                            switch(Map[y2][x])
                            {
                            case ' ':
                                {
                                    Map[y][x] = ' ';
                                    y += 1;
                                    Map[y2][x] = '@';
                                }break;
                            case '!':
                                {
                                    Level = 2;
                                }break;
                                case '*':
                                    {
                                        Hp -= 20;
                                        Map[y][x] = ' ';
                                        y -= 1;
                                        Map[y2][x] = '@';
                                    }break;
                            }
                       }

                       if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) != 0)
                       {
                           int x2 = (x + 1);

                           switch(Map[y][x2])
                           {
                           case ' ':
                            {
                                Map[y][x] = ' ';
                                x += 1;
                                Map[y][x2] = '@';
                            }break;
                           case '!':
                            {
                                Level = 2;
                            }break;
                            case '*':
                                    {
                                        Hp -= 20;
                                        Map[y][x] = ' ';
                                        x -= 1;
                                        Map[y][x2] = '@';
                                    }break;
                           }
                       }
                       if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) != 0)
                       {
                           int x2 = (x - 1);

                           switch(Map[y][x2])
                           {
                           case ' ':
                            {
                                Map[y][x] = ' ';
                                x -= 1;
                                Map[y][x2] = '@';
                            }break;
                           case '!':
                            {
                                Level = 2;
                            }break;
                            case '*':
                                    {
                                        Hp -= 20;
                                        Map[y][x] = ' ';
                                        x -= 1;
                                        Map[y][x2] = '@';
                                    }break;
                           }
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


       }
        Sleep(Gamespeed);
    cout<<"dt:"<<delta_time<<endl;
    cout<<"sd:"<<star_delay<<endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but there was a lot of errors:
'chrono' does not name a type,
'current_time' does not name a type,
'last_time' does not name a type,
'current_time' was not declared in this scope,
'chrono has not been declared,
expected primary-expression before 'float',
expected ';' before 'float',
'last_time' was not declared in this scope,
expected ';' before '}' token

Comment: you have to to include chrono  #include <chrono>

Comment: i also forget call the method .count() when  assigning delta_time

Comment: There is still a lot of errors, so I have added your solution above can you see if everything is correct

Comment: Hi, which compiler are you using? with mingw you need to add the option -std=c++11 so you can use the <chrono> header, also you was using = while comparing y (y=2) you should use y==2 and there was a break; missing before case '@' i update my answer with the code than compile for me using mingw

Comment: Thanks that works but what part of the code slows down the star?

Comment: Basically you are making your own Timer. the difference of (current_time - last_time) give you the total amount of time that passed since the last frame. This is stored in delta_time, so for the star delay you only need to  accumulate delta_time on star_delay and don't do the next move of the start until start_delay is greater than the amount of time you want to wait, in this case 1 second

Comment: Ok but how do I make it wait 1 second because right now the star is moving instantly

Comment: Hi i compile and run the code and the star wait a second before moving, can you update your question with  your current code?

Comment: Ok, I have updated my code under your solution but the level is level 6 now instead of level 1

Comment: Hi sorry it took so long to get back to you but I understand what you meant by adding the c++11 option now. I have recently staring working on this project again is there any way to make the star move every half second instead of every second. if you could update your solution with the star moving every half a seconds that would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, this is in a windowed program (with a GetMessage/DispatchMessage loop), right? Here, you should never block, neither with Sleep() nor with any other long-running operation. This freezes the whole UI as no keyboard input or redraws take place in between. What you can do depends on your design, but an easy way is to trigger a timer that will call the window proc later on and where you can finish the movement.

Another approach is to use threads, but those have a whole different set of complications. Another alternative is I believe a sleep function that feeds the message queue, which would avoid the freeze - you'd have to check the documentation what the name of that function is.

Comment: Okay, my guess was completely wrong, you do not have a windowed program, so the suggestions based on that are wrong, too.